# A tricky looking functional equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Could someone please help me with this problem in ODE's, to show that for a continuous function $f$ which satisfies

> $f(x) = f(x+1) = f(x+\sqrt{2})$

$f$ is constant? I tried showing derivative exists and is zero but nothing came of it. Perhaps something to do with $ 1,\sqrt{2} $ being a rational and irrational, respectively. Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and any $x$ there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $|x + m + n \sqrt{2}| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Robert . Please elaborate. How to formalize? Thanks, Peter

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, taking sequences $m_k$ and $n_k$ such that $x + m_k + n_k \sqrt{2} \to 0$ we have $$f(0) = \lim_{k \to \infty} f(x + m_k + n_k \sqrt{2}) = \lim_{k \to \infty} f(x) = f(x)$$

Comment: Robert, thanks.a lot. Clever, you take a subsequence m_k,n_k and this way k is the only variable.I tried a_{mn} = x+m+n√2, could not handle 2 indices.Thanks, greetings.

Answer (score 2):

By induction,

$$f(x)=f(x+k)=f(x+k\sqrt2)=f(x+k\sqrt2\bmod1).$$

This leaves $f$ few options to be non-constant.